# Can someone explain this Java code (formatting the output using System.out.format) to me?

Tags: java

Enum:

```
public enum tuna {
Veyron("Speed", "R1"),
Reventon("Speed", "R3"),
MclarenF1("Speed", "R3");

public final String style;
public final String theclass;

tuna(String thestyle, String theclasss){
style = thestyle;
theclass = theclasss;
  }
    public String getStyle(){
            return style;
    }

    public String getClasss(){
            return theclass;
    }
}
```

This is the code in my main class that I don't understand:

```
int maxlength = tuna.Veyron.name().length();

    for( tuna cars : tuna.values() ) {
      System.out.format( "%-" + maxlength + "s   %-5s %5s\n", cars.name(), cars.getStyle(), cars.getClasss() );
```

***But the part that I don't understand (well, a little) is this:***

```
"%-" + maxlength + "s   %-5s %5s\n"
```

It seems

```
%-5s
```

changes the width of the tab in between the name of the car (**cars.name()**) and *"Speed"* (**cars.getStyle()**), while

```
%5s
```

changes the width of the tab between "Speed"  and "Class of the car (**cars.getClasss()**) part of the code. (Output seen below:)

Original Output:

[image]

Now if I change %-5s to %-15s or something, the spacing changes in between "Veyron" and "Speed", but it also changes that of "Reventon" and *it's* "Speed".

I changed the name of Veyron to Veyronrrr to make it longer.

```
int maxlength = tuna.Veyronrrr.name().length();
```

This is the output:

[image]

So I what are these pieces of code, and why do they do what they're doing?

Comment: Would the down-voter care to share their reason?  IMWTK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%-5s` means "a string, left-aligned in a column of at least five characters", or if you prefer, "a string, right-padded with spaces until it's at least five characters long".

`%5s` is the same, but right-aligned instead of left-aligned (i.e., left-padded instead of right-padded).

`%-15s` and `%15s`, as you'd expect, are for fifteen-character columns instead of five.

For more information on the syntax of format strings, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax.

Comment: Now when you say "in a column of at least five characters" which column are you talking about? (which color): http://i.imgur.com/izYeh.png

Comment: @Cole: The red column comes from the initial `%-9s` (notice that `Veyronrrr` and `MclarenF1` receive no additional padding, because they're already nine characters wide; only `Reventon` gains a space at the end); the blue column comes from the explicit spaces between `%-9s` and `%-5s`; the green column comes from the `%-5s` in the middle (notice that, since `Speed` is already five characters wide, this doesn't generate any padding); the first space in the yellow column comes from the explicit space between `%-5s` and `%5s`; the last three spaces in the yellow column, plus the whole of the pink

Comment: column, together come from the final `%5s` (because `R1` and `R3` are both only two characters wide, so they get three spaces' padding at the front).

Answer (score 1):

```
"%-" + maxlength + "s   %-5s %5s\n"
```

as you  might be knowing we can indent the printed contents by applying the %2s or %-2s

the 
`"%-" + maxlength + "s` 
means

```
%-(maxlength)s
```

do the first string gets indented according to the maxlength you have provided and if the maxlength will be greater than 5 then the printed material won't be indented as you can't do this

print the string right justified atleast 6 char long if it is actually of length 6 characters.

refer to dennis ritchie C for more lucid explanation of %3s stuff

Answer (score 0):

What the code is trying to do is format the spaces

```
%-5s
```

will add extra spaces **at the end** of the word to complete 5 character. For example if you have:

```
System.out.format(".%-5s.","cat");
```

the output will be

```
.cat  .
```

Now, if you have

```
%5s
```

it will add spaces **before** the word to complete 5 characters. So with a similar example:

```
System.out.format(".%5s.","cat");
```

the output will be

```
.  cat.
```