# I need explain about how to use printf command on this problem

Tags: java

**Input Format**

Every line of input will contain a String followed by an integer. 
Each String will have a maximum of  alphabetic characters, and each integer will be in the inclusive range from  to .

**Output Format**

In each line of output there should be two columns: 
The first column contains the String and is left justified using exactly  characters. 
The second column contains the integer, expressed in exactly  digits; if the original input has less than three digits, you must pad your output's leading digits with zeroes.

**Sample Input**

```
java 100

cpp 65

python 50
```

**Sample Output**

```
================================

java           100 

cpp            065 

python         050 

================================
```

I tried with tab space. but i can't align this correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("================================");
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            String s1=sc.next();
            int x=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print(s1);
            int f=x;
            int count=0;
            while(x!=0){
                x/=10;
                count++;
            }
            if(count==0){System.out.print("\t"+"00"+f);
            }else if(count==3){
                System.out.print("\t"+f);

            }else{
                System.out.print("\t"+"0"+f);
            }System.out.println();
            }
           // System.out.print("\t"+x);

            //Complete this line

        System.out.println("================================");
}  }
```

**My Output**

```
================================

java    100

cpp 065

python  050

================================
```

**Expected Output**

```
================================

java           100 

cpp            065 

python         050

================================
```

Comment: Have a look at the method `String.format()`

Comment: Look at `printf` javadoc.

Comment: System.out.format("%-15s\n", x);

Comment: Use spaces, not tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.format("%-15s\n", x);
```

this should work

Comment: Yes it is working. can you please explain this code?? i haven't used this before your answer.

Comment: @KavinduLanarolle %-15s means "a string, left-aligned in a column of at least five characters" and /n is used for line break. For more information please refer to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981649/can-someone-explain-this-java-code-formatting-the-output-using-system-out-forma
Also, if you found my answer working and useful, please upvote so that it will help the others looking for the same solution